# Is there a MongoDB maximum bson size work around?

Tags: mongodb

The document I am working on is extremely large. It collects user input from an extremely long survey (like survey monkey) and stores the answers in a mongodb database.

I am unsurprisingly getting the following error

```
Error: Document exceeds maximal allowed bson size of 16777216 bytes
```

If I cannot change the fields in my document is there anything I can do? Is there some way to compress down the document, by removing white space or something like that?

**Edit**

Here is the structure of the document

```
Schema({
    id : { type: Number, required: true },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    last_modified: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    data : { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true }
});
```

An example of the data field:

```
{
    id: 65,
    question: {
        test: "some questions",
        answers: [2,5,6]
    }
    // there could be thousands of these question objects
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what a document might look like? Just a subset to show the structure, this will help diagnose.

Comment: Without some context it is really hard to say.Could give us some additional details? Do you need ability to search all of the fields? Is atomic update of a single document required?

Comment: @TomSwifty I added in some more details. I do not need to search through   the data field, which stores all the information.

Comment: Is it not possible to put each question in it's own document?

Comment: @zero323 I do not need to perform any searching, and I'm not 100% sure if atomic update of a single document is required.

Comment: Are you serious that you will NEVER query this data? Why are you using MongoDB again?

Comment: @Sammaye Not sure what you mean. I query the document, and show the contents of the data field in a webpage, but I do not need to perform any searching through that data

Comment: Oh ok yeah that means gridfs really is not a good choice, I suppose you could store the data field in gridfs but hmmm

Comment: Personally I would probably create two separate collections - first containing all important metadata for given questionnaire and second with single document per question in each questionnaire.

Comment: This would create a huge document in memory as well (as you fetch it), and if you've got multiple users, it's going to be very inefficient. Strongly consider a schema change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you can do is to **build your own mongoDB** :-). Mongodb is an open [source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo) and the limitation about the size of a document is rather arbitrary to enforce a [better schema design](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON%20Document%20Size). You can just modify [this line](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/4211c6a8de32fa774b1c28fb82a96f965fd550b7/src/mongo/bson/util/builder.h#L50) and build it for yourself. Be careful with this.

The most straight forward idea is to have **each small question in a different document** with a field which reference to its parent.

Another idea is to **limit number of documents in the parent**. Lets say you limit is N elements then the parent looks like this:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId(),
  id : { type: Number, required: true },
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },  // you can store it only for the first element
  last_modified: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, // the same here
  data : [{
    id: 65,
    question: {
        test: "some questions",
        answers: [2,5,6]
    }
  }, ... up to N of such things {}
  ]
}
```

This way modifying number N you can make sure that you will be in 16 MB of BSON. And in order to read the whole survey you can select

`db.coll.find({id: the Id you need})` and then combine the whole survey on the application level. Also do not forget to ensureIndex on `id`.

Try different things, do a benchmark on your data and see what works for you.

Comment: I think I will have to go with what you mentioned - "each small question in a different document"

Comment: Interesting solution to the size limit, though "with great power comes great responsibility"!

Comment: This wont actually solve the size problem since the data field will actually be bigger than in blob format, the solution is to factor off the questions to a questions collection

Comment: I just wanted to highlight that mongodb is open source and you are free to modify it in any way you want. But surely you need to know what are you doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `gridfs`. It allows you to store documents in chunks. Here's the link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/

Comment: Gridfs would not be a good idea here, searching through those documents would be impossible with indexes

Comment: Per @bejm's comments, they don't do any searching.

Comment: It depends what the needs are, and what kind of performance he's expecting, but good point on the speed challenges.

Comment: Yeah clarification is that he requires to query the document itself, gridfs won't work

Comment: A schema change would be far better than storing large blobs of binary documents. It nearly completely defeats the value of using MongoDB.

Comment: My understanding was that he was querying only the top level fields, and not the chunked data. However, I have not tested gridfs much.