# MongoDb error caused by a big result set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I m actually facing a problem when trying to get a full resultset (~40 result).
Each object has ~260 childs references and other objects packed in.

Actually, when I try to display 30 objects, it works. But when I try with 40 it doesn't.
Each object is correct, no data is invalid.

It seems that I've exceed the maximum size(4 or 16 mb) authorized by mongoDb or defaultly Mongoskin (the library that I use to access mongodb), and mongodb close the pool connection to my application.

So how can I increase the maximum document size, or the maximum result set size, to display everything I need ?

**EDIT** : My collection size is 8Mb (from MongoVue informations)

**EDIT 2 :** 
The code I use to get my data :

```
db.collection("roadmap").find({}).toArray()
```

An screenshot of my db :
[image]

**EDIT 3** : I changed the way I was exploiting my data using

```
@em.collection('roadmap').find({}, (err, resultCursor)=>
      nextItem = (err, item)=>
        if !item)
          return

        console.log item
        resultCursor.nextObject(nextItem)
      resultCursor.nextObject(nextItem)
    )
```

It doesn't work neither, the request is executed, and then, I lose my mongodb connection. If I comment this piece of code in my application, all is working great.

**EDIT 4** : Full stack trace, it's more a library problem than a db problem

```
Error: parseError occured
  at [object Object].<anonymous> (/var/www/xxxxxx/Ws/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:192:34)
  at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/xxxxxx/Ws/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:393:20)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
  at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)
  at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:422:5)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
```

Comment: Can you post the query that's giving you the problem, an example document (abbreviated is fine), and the exact error messages that you get? Also, MongoDB and driver versions are helpful.

Comment: I added the code and a screenshot :-)

Comment: I think the problem is `.toArray()`, not the `find`. But I don't see the exact error message, so it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: I dont have anything else than "Parse error" in the log console :-/

Comment: And I m using https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin . What is the alternative of toArray ?

Comment: Can it be that since it is a big result set, the cursor expires? I think that you can set a timeout time to the cursor. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/

Comment: Can you try the same thing from the mongo shell? 40 documents, even with 260 fields, is not much data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715229/is-there-a-mongodb-maximum-bson-size-work-around

Comment: @wdberkeley, it works in the mongoshell

Comment: @Disposer, I read your post, but it's apparently not a size problem with mongo documents, and I cant redesign my DB actually

Comment: @leojg it seems that the problem occurs on the 25 (no matter the object) but changing the timeout doesn't seem to work :/. In fact, I can batchsize only to 25, after, I got the error.

Comment: @Skahrz Looking at your stack trace I think that the problem might be that you have some non-utf8 char in some of the documents.

Comment: I will check. But I can see the whole result using skip and limit. It s just when I want to get the full resultset in one time that I ve the error

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to Create and index for the collection 'roadmap'.

```
 db.roadmap.ensureIndex({zone:1});
```

This is just used to retrive data faster than before, refer http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/

Change the Find as follows, there is no need of toArray function since the data is already an array.

```
 db.roadmap.find({},function(err,data){
 if(err){
 console.log(err);
}
console.log(data); 
)
```

This finds all the data in the roadmap collection.The index is used when the data set is huge. Hope this helps.

Comment: It didn't change anything :x. And I m using a library between, the data is not directly displayed in the secodn parameter of the callback.

Comment: try using mongoose instead of mongoskin, it gives me perfect result for my 26800 records.

Comment: I cant refactor the whole app actually

Comment: i will check for some other solution using mongoskin

Comment: An index will do nothing to help here, the collection is roadmap not the field. Also that change in find will not help at all

Answer (score 1):

That error is being emitted by the [mongo node driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/V1.4.4/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js#L192) "below" mongoskin. In the [connection](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/V1.4.4/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js) file, there are several places that can emit this error. To see the *actual* error, give the connection a logger and it will print the thing. That will tell you where in the connection you have a problem, and what it is. Note that mongoskin is using version 1.4.4 of the driver, so if it is a bug they might have fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I m actually using a version of mongoskin using the 1.4.4 mongodriver. I m actually looking for a method to give a logger to mongodb driver through mongoskin to give your more information

Comment: You'll probably need to reach into the guts of the connection object after you create it and add the property.

Comment: Okay, so I fond that the error is here : https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/V1.4.4/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js#l386-395