# Architecture MongoDb documents to support multi events

Tags: mongodb, architecture, software-design

I have the scenario that an Event must support multiple dates and users can apply for events.

**I found the next solution:**

A document can have an array of EventTime that include the time of the event and an array of the users id's.

```
{
  id: "asdasd-asdasd",
  name: "Event 1",
  ...
  timeEvent: [ {Time: "10-12-2015", Users:[UserId1, UserId2 ]}, ...  ]
}
```

**The problem** is, the document can exceeds the 16Mb limit.

PS: The main goal is to reuse the same event for different days.

Comment: What type of queries user/admin is going to use? Store data based on that and if you are exceeding 16MB limit then architecture is not correct and you need to split the data in multiple collections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 90% are Read Operations. 

The problem of slipting data is to know when I should create more TimeEvents? Image you have an option to Create the same event Weekly (ex: all fridays)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a MongoDB maximum bson size work around?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715229/is-there-a-mongodb-maximum-bson-size-work-around)